# dwa_planner: trajectory_cloud topic not showing up

Tags: ros, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When we run move_base with dwa_local_planner, doing a `rostopic list` shows a topic named /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/trajectory_cloud, and another named /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/cost_cloud. However, nothing ever seems to get posted to these topics, even when there's an active nav goal in play. Should we be seeing output on these topics? We're debugging some strange behavior and would sure like to see what the planner is thinking.

Thanks,

Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192143/dwa_planner:-trajectory_cloud-topic-not-showing-up/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-07**:
I think there are parameters that you have to set to enable these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to visualize the trajectory cloud and the cost cloud, you have to set the `publish_traj_pc` and `publish_cost_grid_pc` parameters respectively. These aren't dynamic_reconfigure parameters, so you'll have to set them directly in your local planner parameters.

This isn't well documented. I had to go to the source to find the relevant parameters: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/ab3cdff51fa062845be8da4cf1e58f5fc56abab9/dwa_local_planner/src/dwa_planner.cpp#L154-L163

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-09-09**:
Great, thanks Austin!